# How to open phone dialer (Keypad) with c# windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, pinvoke

in my app i want to copy a phone number to clipboard then open the **phone dialer** ( *keypad* ) to paste the number there. without using **PhoneCallTask** to make a call

[image: Keypad]

i can't use PhoneCallTask because it can't support USSD numbers for exemple to check my phone funds the number is " ***100#** "

the error message  **'please enter service codes directly from the phone's keypad'**

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In XAML:

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Text="{Binding UserInput, Mode=TwoWay}" InputScope="{Binding UserInputScope}"/>
```

In code behind: Make a dependency property UserInputScope then set this to

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty UserInputTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UserInputType", typeof (InputScope), typeof (ManualTypeView), new PropertyMetadata(default(InputScope)));

public InputScope UserInputType
{
    get { return (InputScope) GetValue(UserInputTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UserInputTypeProperty, value); }
}
```

Set UserInputType to

```
this.UserInputType = new InputScope
{
    Names =
        {
            new InputScopeName
                {NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber}
        }
};
```